# How to check if EmptyView of my ListView is shown in Android?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I am using a ListView and I show an EmptyView if the list is empty. How can I check if this View is shown with a boolean variable?

Here the code for my ListView:

```
deviceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.DeviceList);
ListAdapter listenAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, deviceArray);

//add a view which is shown if the ListView is empty
deviceList.setEmptyView( findViewById( R.id.empty_list_view ) );
deviceList.setAdapter(listenAdapter);
```

Comment: See if the `ListView`'s adapter is `null` or if it has any values in it.

Comment: how can I do that? The ListAdapter has no such method, here the link t the Android developers page http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

Comment: You use the superclass(interface in this case) but your adapter is an `ArrayAdapter` so use that. Example: `boolean isEmptyViewShown = ((ArrayAdapter) deviceList.getAdapter() == null)
    || (((ArrayAdapter) deviceList.getAdapter()).getCount() == 0);`

Comment: I tried your code but the boolean variable is always true even if I add items to the list. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: You have to run that code **after** you add the items to the list(or run it when you need to know the status of the view), that `boolean` variable is not going to update itself.

Comment: That was the solution! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the xml using the "special" android ids. If you use this code in your layout xml file the empty text shows up automatically when required:

```
<ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"    android:id="@id/android:list"/>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"   android:text="@string/no_tasks" android:id="@id/android:empty"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
```

The textview with the android:empty id only shows when the android:list component is empty.

I hope that helps.

Comment: That is not my problem, I am already able to show the empty list. But I want to have a boolean variable which has "true" if the empty list is shown

Comment: Ahh, indeed, apologies. I need to RTFQ ;-)